# Regular expression that finds prices

Tags: regex

Regular expression to extract all prices in a text, where prices will use "," as decimal separator. There are no thousands separator and they will be followed by " UDS". For example:

```
1500 USD
9 USD
0,53 USD
12,01 USD
```

---

```
^[^0]\d+(\,)?[0-9]{0,2} USD
```

It works for:

```
1500 USD
12,01 USD
```

but it does not work for:

```
9 USD
0,53 USD
```

Comment: Why not remove `" USD"`? If these prices are somewhere in a longer text, why use `^`? Then use `(\d[\d,]*) USD`

Comment: `[^0]\d+` forces the the left-side to be at least two digits long, and also doesn't allow it to be zero. It should be `([^0]\d*|0)`.

Comment: @vlumi would this be the same to write just ^\d+(\,)?[0-9]{0,2} USD

Comment: Your original pattern looks like it's attempting to exclude amounts that start with `0`, but then you claim that `0,53 USD` should match but doesn't. Do you want this to match or not? What about just `0 USD` or `0,00 USD`?

Comment: @CAustin Good one, it should not exclude amounts that starts with `0`, and yes it should match `0 USD` or `0,00 USD` too.

Comment: What if I want to extract only numbers with decimals from strings containing " USD", but without extracting " USD" after the number?

Comment: If that's what you want, then you should edit your question. Also, please add at least one additional tag that indicates which tool or programming language you're using. Regex behaves differently and supports different features depending on the flavor being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern `^[^0]\d+(\,)?[0-9]{0,2} USD` in this part `^[^0]` the first ^ is an anchor asserting the start of the string.

The second ^ is at the start inside a character class and its meaning is different. It creates a negated character class meaning that it can not start with 0.

The following part `(\,)?[0-9]{0,2}` is an optional group to match a comma(note that you don't have to escape it) and 0-2 digits. This way a value like `1,` would also match.

There is no language tagged, but if a positive lookahead and a negative lookbehind  are supported you might use this pattern to extract prices in a text using word boundaries to prevent the digits and USD being part of a larger word. `(?<!\S)` asserts that what is directly on the left is not a non whitespace character.

If you want the whole match instead of only the prices, you can match USD instead of using the positive lookahead.

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?(?= USD\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kAoETC/3)

Another option is to use a capturing group instead of a lookahead. `(?:^|\s)` asserts the start of the string or match a whitespace character.

```
(?:^|\s)(\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?) USD\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kAoETC/4)

Comment: In both regex, if you have for example `2,345 USD`, will match `345` or `345 USD`, which is not correct of course. First as we want to match numbers with decimals only, second we want to match the whole number, not only what is after the comma. So your both regex works fine, it would just not need to match nothing in case there are numbers followed by more than 2 decimals after the comma.

Comment: @user3536226 You are right, I have updated both regexes in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript

```
/^\d{1,}(,\d{2}){0,1} USD$/
```

```js
    var regex = /^\d{1,}(,\d{2}){0,1} USD$/;
    // true result
    console.log(regex.test('9 USD'));
    console.log(regex.test('0,53 USD'));
    console.log(regex.test('12,01 USD'));
    console.log(regex.test('1500 USD'));
    // false result
    console.log(regex.test(' USD'));
    console.log(regex.test('0,5,3 USD'));
    console.log(regex.test('12,0124 USD'));
    console.log(regex.test('1s500 USD'));
```

OR sed in action:

```
% echo "1500 USD 9 USD 0,53 USD 12,01 USD" |sed  -E 's/[0-9]+(,[0-9][0-9]){0,1} USD/TRUE/g'
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

option -E enables extended regular expressions

Comment: `\d{1,}` --> `\d+`, `(,\d{2}){0,1}` --> `(,\d{2})?` or better `(?:,\d{2})?`

Comment: @Toto absolutely right, just legible or few characters.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that this simple expression would return what we might want:

```
([0-9,.]+)
```

regardless of other text contents that we might have, since validation is not required here, assuming that our prices are valid.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/HIB9PL/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"([0-9,.]+)";
        string input = @"500 USD 9 USD 0,53 USD 12,01 USD
1500 USD 12,01 USD 9 USD 0,53 USD  1500 USD 12,01 USD 9 USD 0,53 USD ";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /([0-9,.]+)/gm;
const str = `500 USD 9 USD 0,53 USD 12,01 USD
1500 USD 12,01 USD 9 USD 0,53 USD  1500 USD 12,01 USD 9 USD 0,53 USD `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```